# Python pandas use fillna() to avoid error splitting on NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data = { 'col0': ['1%2%', '3%4%'], 'col1': [np.nan, np.nan], 'col2': ['+1-2', '+2-4'], 'col3': [np.nan, '+2-4'], 'col4': [np.nan, np.nan] })

my_df[['col0a', 'col0b']] = my_df['col0'].fillna('%').str.split('%', expand = True).iloc[:, 0:2]
my_df[['col1a', 'col1b']] = my_df['col1'].fillna('%').str.split('%', expand = True).iloc[:, 0:2]
my_df[['col2a', 'col2b']] = my_df['col2'].str.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-])', expand=True)
my_df[['col3a', 'col3b']] = my_df['col3'].str.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-])', expand=True)
my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']] = my_df['col4'].str.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-])', expand=True)

my_df
```

This throws an error on the line `my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']]` since the entire column is `NaN` values. For `col1`, there is no error thrown since we fillna with `%`, and the split then splits on the `%` resulting in two columns with empty strings, which is exactly what we want.

What `fillna()` can we add to `col4` such that it won't throw an error? The split for col4 is more complex (looking for the pattern of +#-#) than the split for col1. We've tried `fillna('+-')` but this does not work. In general, we are looking for a solution that outputs empty strings for `col4a` and `col4b` when `col4` has `NaN` as its value.

**Edit:** worded differently, I need a string for fillna that, when passed to `.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-])', expand=True)`, would result in 2 empty strings, although perhaps I can replace with something like `fillna(+9999-9999)` and then replace 9999 with empty strings...

Comment: The problem is not that the split returns NaN. The problem is that the split is not happening because the NaN exists, and replacing NaN with empty string does not work because the split output expects 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (probably) better solution is to use `.str.extract` instead of `.str.split`, which is better-suited for your purposes:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data = { 'col0': ['1%2%', '3%4%'], 'col1': [np.nan, np.nan], 'col2': ['+1-2', '+2-4'], 'col3': [np.nan, '+2-4'], 'col4': [np.nan, np.nan] })
my_df = my_df.fillna('')

pat1 = r'(\d+%)(\d+%)'
pat2 = r'([+-](?:[\d]+|K))([+-](?:[\d]+|K))'

my_df[['col0a', 'col0b']] = my_df['col0'].str.extract(pat1)
my_df[['col1a', 'col1b']] = my_df['col1'].str.extract(pat1)
my_df[['col2a', 'col2b']] = my_df['col2'].str.extract(pat2)
my_df[['col3a', 'col3b']] = my_df['col3'].str.extract(pat2)
my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']] = my_df['col4'].str.extract(pat2)
my_df = my_df.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
>>> my_df
   col0 col1  col2  col3 col4 col0a col0b col1a col1b col2a col2b col3a col3b col4a col4b
0  1%2%       +1-2               1%    2%                +1    -2                        
1  3%4%       +2-4  +2-4         3%    4%                +2    -4    +2    -4
```

Comment: this is great. I think I would add `fillna('')` to the end of each of the last 5 lines since I'd prefer the empty string over the `NaN`, but other wise this looks really good

Comment: @Canovice please check the answer now. I've done that what you said, except a little more concisely ;)

Comment: I guess 1 issue here is that `col0a`, `col0b` lose their `%` sign in the output

Comment: Easily remedied. Please check the answer now @Canovice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but this 2-line solution is better than the current 8-line solution I have that uses an if: else: block.

```
my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']] = my_df['col4'].fillna('+999999-999999').str.split('(?<=[\d]|K)(?=[+-])', expand=True)
my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']] = my_df[['col4a', 'col4b']].replace('+999999', '').replace('-999999', '')
```